# Python BeautifulSoup parsing specific text

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am parsing an html file and I want to find the part of the file where it says "Smaller Reporting Company" and either has an "X" or Checkbox next to it or doesn't. The checkbox is typically done with the Wingdings font or an ascii code. In the HTML below you'll see it has an `&#254;` in wingdings next to it.

I have no problem showing the results of a regular expression search for the text, but I'm having trouble going the next step and looking for a check box.

I will be using this to parse a number of different html files that won't all follow the same format, but most of them will use a table and ascii text like this example.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV align="left">Indicate by check mark whether the registrant is a large accelerated filer, an accelerated filer, a non-accelerated filer, or a smaller reporting company. See the definitions of &#147;large accelerated filer,&#148; &#147;accelerated filer&#148; and &#147;smaller reporting company&#148;. (Check one):
</DIV>

<DIV align="center">
<TABLE style="font-size: 10pt" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<!-- Begin Table Head -->
<TR valign="bottom">
    <TD width="22%">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD width="3%">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD width="22%">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD width="3%">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD width="22%">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD width="3%">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD width="22%">&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
<TR></TR>
<!-- End Table Head -->
<!-- Begin Table Body -->
<TR valign="bottom">
    <TD align="center" valign="top"><FONT style="white-space: nowrap"> Large accelerated filer <FONT style="font-family: Wingdings">&#111;</FONT></FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="top"><FONT style="white-space: nowrap">Accelerated filer <FONT style="font-family: Wingdings">&#111;</FONT></FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="top"><FONT style="white-space: nowrap"> Non-accelerated filer <FONT style="font-family: Wingdings">&#111;</FONT> </FONT>
    <FONT style="white-space: nowrap">(Do not check if a smaller reporting company)</FONT>
    </TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD align="center" valign="top"><FONT style="white-space: nowrap"> Smaller reporting company <FONT style="font-family: Wingdings">&#254;</FONT></FONT></TD>
</TR>
<!-- End Table Body -->
</TABLE>
</DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

Here is my Python code:

```
import os, sys, string, re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

rawDataFile = "testfile1.html"
f = open(rawDataFile)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
f.close()

search = soup.findAll(text=re.compile('[sS]maller.*[rR]eporting.*[cC]ompany'))
print search
```

Question:
How could I set this up to have a second search that is dependent upon the first search? So when I find "smaller reporting company" I can search the next few lines to see if there is an ascii code? I've been going through the soup docs. I tried to do find and findNext but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: I bet that you should have corrected _"has an "X" or Checkbox next to it "_ to _"has an "X" **ON** Checkbox next to it "_ and you didn't. This disconcerted me and troubled my understanding of your question. Don't you care about being well understood ?

Comment: _"In the HTML below you'll see it has an þ in wingdings next to it."_  ?? where ??

Comment: What do you call 'ascii code' ? Is it &#111; and &#254; ??

Comment: -1 Confusion reigns. "an þ in wingdings next to it" turns out on microscopically close inspection to be not `LATIN SMALL LETTER P` but `&#254;` aka `LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN`. Anyone wondering what the relevance of this character is may like to read http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html ... 111 is an empty box, 254 is a ticked box

Comment: I should have added back ticks around the `&#254;` code when originally posting. I corrected the original post.

Comment: You stll haven't explained "ascii code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the position of the wingding character won't change, you can use `.next`.

```
>>> nodes = soup.findAll(text=re.compile('[sS]maller.*[rR]eporting.*[cC]ompany'))
>>> nodes[-1].next.next  # last item in list is the only good one... kinda crap
u'&#254;'
```

Or you can go up, and then `find` from there:

```
>>> nodes[-1].parent.find('font',style="font-family: Wingdings").next
u'&#254;'
```

Or you could do it the other way round:

```
>>> soup.findAll(text='&#254;')[0].previous.previous
u' Smaller reporting company '
```

This assume that you know the wingding caharcters you're looking for.

The last strategy has the added bonus of filtering out other crap that your regex is catching, which I suppose you don't really want; you can then just cycle through results knowing that you're only working on the right list, so you can peruse `if` to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You may try iterating through the structure and checking for values inside the inner tags or checking for values in the outer tags.  I can't remember off hand how to do it and I ended up using lxml for this, but I think bsoup may be able to do this.

If you can't get bsoup to do it check out lxml.  It is potentially faster depending upon what you are doing.  It also has hooks for using bsoup with lxml.

Answer (score 0):

`lxml` has a tolerant HTML parser. You don't need bsoup (which is now deprecated by its author) and you should avoid regexes for parsing HTML.

Here is a first rough cut at what you are looking for:

```
guff = """\
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD>
[snip]
</DIV></BODY></HTML>
"""
from lxml.html import fromstring
doc = fromstring(guff)
for td_el in doc.iter('td'):
    font_els = list(td_el.iter('font'))
    if not font_els: continue
    print
    for el in font_els:
        print (el.text, el.attrib)
```

This produces:

```
(' Large accelerated filer ', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap'})
('o', {'style': 'font-family: Wingdings'})

('Accelerated filer ', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap'})
('o', {'style': 'font-family: Wingdings'})

(' Non-accelerated filer ', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap'})
('o', {'style': 'font-family: Wingdings'})
('(Do not check if a smaller reporting company)', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap
'})

(' Smaller reporting company ', {'style': 'white-space: nowrap'})
(u'\xfe', {'style': 'font-family: Wingdings'})
```

Comment: The problem with lxml is the dependency on libxml, which is not always available -- e.g. you can't use it at all with Jython. The beauty of BS is that it's just one file of pure Python.